# Issue with telefonica/orchestrator

Tags: docker, centos, iot, fiware

I am dealing with an issue while trying to use telefonica/orchestrator and I hope anyone can help me with it.
My server is CentOS 7.3 and I am trying to build an IoT platform using docker version 1.10.3 and FIWARE. I have successfuly installed all necessary containers (mongodb, orion, mysql, keystone, keypass, pep and orchestrator). Everything works fine except orchestrator. When I am trying to

```
curl localhost:8084/v1.0/version
```

the response is:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to ask API orchestrator before orchestrator is completed started. Just wait some seconds before do that.
BTW telefonica/orchestrator is not part of FIWARE.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I have tried it many times and waited for more than some seconds but with no luck. I know that telefonica/orchestrator is not part of FIWARE but it is very relevant to it, that is why I included it.